# QTableView shows 1d data in exactly one row/column. How to show it two-dimensionally?

Tags: qt, qtableview, qabstractitemview

Say I have a one-dimensional QStandardItemModel and a QTableView instance:

```
QStandardItemModel model;
for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
    QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString::number(i));
    model.appendRow(item);
}

QTableView tableView;
tableView.setModel(&model);
tableView.show();
```

This shows the data in the first column, but I want to show it in a two-dimensional way like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Additionally the user should be able to select the data, which means that a custom QStyledItemDelegate probably isn't the way to go to implement this.

So one needs to create a custom QAbstractItemView, where the documentation is unfortunately a bit lacking in my opinion. Help?

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/44705/solved-how-to-show-one-dimensional-data-two-dimensionally is a copy of this question with `QAbstractProxyModel` as the solution.

Comment: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32960-QAbstractProxyModel-tutorial-or-advice was also helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want show data as 2d array, you shoul write another loop. For example this:

```
int counter = 0;
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        counter++;
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString::number(counter));
        model->setItem(i,j,item);
    }

ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

On my computer this works exactly as you want.

Secondly. User can do different actions with cells. QTableView have a few very good signals. With this signal, we can communicate with cells. I write one more code snippet.

```
int counter = 0;
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        counter++;
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString::number(counter));
        model->setItem(i,j,item);
    }
connect(ui->tableView,SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(clickedIndex(QModelIndex )));
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
//...
void MainWindow::clickedIndex(QModelIndex index)
{
    if(index.isValid())
    {
        ui->tableView->model()->setData(index,QString("you press %1 , %2 cell").arg(index.row()).arg(index.column()));
    }
}
```

In this example, when user clicked on some cell, text in the cell tell him number of this cell. 
I hope,it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this creates 2d data and displays it two-dimensionally. What I'm trying to achieve is to show 1d data both two-dimensionally using something like QTableView (which doesn't work, so I'll probably have to write my own QAbstractItemView) but also one-dimensonally using QListView.